# MWPM / Union Find Implementations for 3D Toric Code

Tags: surface-code, topological-quantum-computing

I am currently looking into 3D surface codes and was wondering if there are open-source implementations for decoders like MWPM or the Union Find decoder. I found quite a lot of different GitHub repos using 2D toric codes for both MWPM and Union Find, but none with a 3D implementation.

That is a bit odd, so I figured I just did not look good enough. Do you maybe have a tip where I could find such an implementation?

Comment: Is the 3d toric code decodable by matching in the first place?